# multiple items inside the rightIconButton of a MaterialUI ListItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to attach multiple items to the `rightIconButton` inside a `ListItem`.

I'm using [Material UI v0.20](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/list) and React@15.6.2

```
      <ListItem
        rightIconButton={
          <span>
            <RaisedButton />
            <TrashIcon />
          </span>
        }
      />
```

**How can i wrap the items to avoid the warning?**

*Warning: Unknown prop `onKeyboardFocus` on `span` tag. Remove this prop from the element.*

[image]

[image: Edit xenodochial-nash-smuhi]

Comment: Please, could you edit your questions add attache the error as text instead of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using HOC:

```js
function Single() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RaisedButton>Hello</RaisedButton>
      <RaisedButton>wORLD</RaisedButton>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
      <List>
        <ListItem rightIconButton={<Single />} />
      </List>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MaterialUI rightIconButton]

Comment: Using "react": "15.6.2" and <> </> is not supported. Also `React.Fragment` is throwing errors as well.

Comment: So edit your question... your react is outdated too (maybe make a sandbox?)

Comment: @CristianMuscalu Try <div/> not <span/>

Comment: so try one HOC which wraps `RaisedButton` and `TrashIcon`

Comment: Added codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-righticonbutton-dpyxk

Comment: I tried separating them to a function and calling from there, but same shit.

Comment: @CristianMuscalu check the answer, used hoc without errors

Comment: I didnt copy it, clearly u can see I said to try hoc 20 min before your answer

Comment: Huh .. this way seems to work. I previosly created a rengerGroup() function and calling it with this.renderGroup() and that's why it was throwing the same errors,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A custom component will help to remove the warning:

```
function GroupedButtons(props) {

  return (
    <span>
       <RaisedButton>Hello</RaisedButton>
       <RaisedButton>WORLD</RaisedButton>
     </span>
  )
}

...

function App() {

  ...

  <ListItem
     rightIconButton={
        <GroupedButtons />
     }
  />
```

**Working example**:

[image: Edit MaterialUI rightIconButton]